# how to run one webcam in different window simultaneously in pyqt5 using opencv

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, pyqt5

I want to run my laptop webcam in 2 window parallel. But I can't run both cameras simultaneously. I can run one camera at a time. How to run one camera in two windows clicking buttons in pyqt5. I listened that it can be done by "threading". but I'm not experienced at that. Would someone please help me out with this code using thread or whatever.I am unable to upload "main.ui" file, that's why I gave the image.

[image: main.ui file screeshot]

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
import qdarkstyle  # builtin dark theme
import sys
import os
import cv2
import time
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from threading import Thread
import concurrent.futures as cf

# =======================
# load all ui file
# =======================

ui, _ = loadUiType( 'main.ui' )

class MainApp( QMainWindow, ui ):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        QMainWindow.__init__( self )
        self.setupUi( self )
        self.connect = 0
        self.initUi()
        self.buttons()


def initUi( self ):
    self.setWindowTitle( 'webcam' )
 

def buttons( self ):
    self.connectWebcam1.clicked.connect(self.callCamera1 )
    self.connectWebCam2.clicked.connect(self.callCamera2)

def callCamera1(self):
   
   self.connectCamera1Entry()

def callCamera2(self):
   
   self.connectCamera2Exit()
   
   
def connectCamera1Entry( self ):
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture( 0 )
    
    while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('camera 1[Entry]', frame)
        
        if cv2.waitKey( 1 ) & 0xFF == ord( 'q' ):
            break
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def connectCamera2Exit(self):
   
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture( 0 )
    
    while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('camera 2[Exit]', frame)
        
        if cv2.waitKey( 1 ) & 0xFF == ord( 'q' ):
            break
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def main():
    app = QApplication( sys.argv )
    app.setStyleSheet( qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5() )  # load the builtin dark theme
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  Because the camera device is already busy with connectCamera1Entry(),  Reading will fail in connectCamera2Exit().

This failure happening in the v4l2 layer in linux not in Qt layer.

Some thoughts like closing and opening the devices will work.

Comment: I'm using windows. There is just one device (my laptop webcam). But I want to show the camera in 2 windows concurrently by clicking connectWebcam1 & connectWebcam2 buttons.

Comment: With Directshow layer also you will have the same problem I guess.  As far my knowledge you can have two renderers, reading the data from the hardware will be only once.